# Storing Product images

Tags: image

I have created new folder for storing product images and i am trying to store image directly in "product" folder but it is saving in "cache" folder. I dont want to store images in "cache" folder.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you have cache activated? (System>Cache Management)

Comment: no cache is not activated